# Cluster algebra associated to a d-gon

Tags: abstract-algebra, cluster-algebra

Recently I have been doing some reading on cluster algebras, for example [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.6263.pdf). When defining the cluster algebras associated to a $d$-gon, they claim that the cluster and coefficient variables of $A_{d−3}$ are in bijection with the diagonals and sides of the $d$-gon, and the clusters are in bijection with triangulations of the $d$-gon, but I'm not really sure how to prove it and I don't think this is simply just the matter of counting.

I'd appreciate any ideas or references, or both.

Comment: Section 2.2 of the linked paper is a proof of the property you describe, if you're having problem with an aspect of that proof you should describe more clearly which step you're having trouble with.

Comment: By definition, the initial cluster comes from a chosen triangulation. The fact that clusters are in bijection with triangulations come from the fact that "flipping" a diagonal corresponds to mutation, and the fact that all triangulations are connected by a sequence of "flips".